# Android error ANR when I make a lot of buttons

Tags: android, button, android-anr-dialog

I don't understand about this problem. My android application need to generate Custom button.
It can work if I have less than 144 buttons but if I generate button more over 144 buttons.
it can't work(Forcse Closed) and show error in log cast like this.....

```
       ANR in com.Sanuk.mahjongandroid (com.Sanuk.mahjongandroid/.MainActivity)
       Load: 0.92 / 1.0 / 0.83
       CPU usage from 21998ms to 0ms ago:
       98% 3225/com.Sanuk.mahjongandroid: 98% user + 0% kernel
         0% 1141/com.android.voicedialer: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 30 minor
```

I'm sure, It 's not error in my code. What wrong?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that you are freezing the UI Thread by doing too much thing. The UI Thread is the thread that is responsible for view painting on screen and intercepting touches from users. It should be as free as possible to get a fluid app.

If you have heavy processing to do like creating a lot of buttons, here are some alternatives :

- use an AsyncTask, although here, you should take care of creating the button in the background, but adding them in the UI Thread.
- why don't you use a list ?